# Ruby on rails application fails to run on one machine but runs on another (same setup)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

I have problem with moving Ruby on Rails app between two machines,
Both of them have exactly the same OS and setup (Arch linux x86_64 updated today),
(well, this can not be true, because this problem happens, but I'm unable to spot any differences at the moment)
both have rails in version 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3

On my laptop everything works fine, app runs correctly, 
on desktop command

```
rake assets:precompile
```

fails with error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'jquery'
(...)
```

I have this in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

and gem 'jquery-rails' in my Gemfile (bundle install completes successfully)
but this is probably irrelevant - rake fails in exactly same wqay without this gem installed.

I tried running rails server, webpage shows error:

```
cannot load such file -- sass
(in [path])
```

Problem must lay somewhere in my ruby/rails installation on desktop, app source is kept in git, both machines have the same revision with clean working dir - tmp is in .gitignore.
Asset pipeline is enabled in config/application.rb

I tried the following:

1. Deleted tmp directory
2. Reinstalled rails, jquery and couple of other gems
3. Used other environments (rake fails in all of them)
4. Downloaded jquery and put it  in assets dir (this is supposed to be automatic in rails),
   i this case rake assets:precompile fails on sass stylesheet compilation (I have sass-rails installed!)

I must be missing something obvious here, anyone had this problem before?

Do I need to purge my ruby installation or is there a simpler way to solve this?

(ps. Sorry about my poor English)

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here, but have you tried using `bundle exec rake`?

Comment: Yes, also failed. I solved the problem using brute-force :  Removed ~/.gem dir, uninstalled ruby, purged /usr/lib/ruby/gems and reinstalled everything from scratch. Problem went away. I wish I could know what caused it.